# While retrieving double from json it adds extra numbers (Swift, IOS)

Tags: ios, json, swift, list, decimal

I am retrieving double value in string format from JSON and it adds an extra **0000000001** in String after decimal value.

JSON

```
{
    varEmpCode: "00001",
    decPOBValue_Product: 12967.68, 
},
{
    varEmpCode: "00002",
    decPOBValue_Product: 8645.12, 
},
{
    varEmpCode: "00003",
    decPOBValue_Product: 9185.44, 
},
{
    varEmpCode: "00004",
    decPOBValue_Product: 8683.24, 
}
```

Code for parse JSON

```
if list.count>0{
    for i in 0...list.count-1 {             
        let obj = lstDailyWorkDetailModal(varEmpCode: list[i]["varEmpCode"].stringValue, 
        decPOBValue_Product: list[i]["decPOBValue_Product"].stringValue)                       
        self.detailReportModal.append(obj)
    }
}
```

The output I am getting in the list

```
decPOBValue_Product: 12967.68, 
decPOBValue_Product: 8645.120000000001, // Wrong
decPOBValue_Product: 9185.440000000001, // Wrong
decPOBValue_Product: 8683.24,
```

Comment: try ```(list[i]["decPOBValue_Product"] as NSString).doubleValue```

Comment: Yes, but why does it add an extra 0000000001 in some values?

Comment: that is the normal behaviour. Read [this](https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)

Comment: First of all don't use `SwiftyJSON`, use `Codable`. To display a `Double` format the value with `NumberFormatter` or `String(format`. And the `list.count>0{` check is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to real numbers representation. Some numbers can't be represented correctly by computers ( float or double ). That's quite logic since bits representation induce a granularity.

To deal with prices, use one of these types :

- **int** ( multiply by 100 to represent in cents )
- **NSDecimal** ( as Apple does in the StoreKit, if I remember correctly )
- **String** ( for storage purpose only, obviously )

In your case, I would say decimal type is the right option.